# Setting svn:ignore flag using svnkit

Tags: svn, svnkit, svnignore

I am using [SVNKit](http://www.svnkit.com) in my application. I have a scenario wherein certain files should be ignored when doing svn operations. i.e. I need to set the svn:ignore property for certain patterns.

How do I do that using SVNKit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [ISVNOptions](http://svnkit.com/kb/javadoc/org/tmatesoft/svn/core/wc/ISVNOptions.html) class.

It has a [`addIgnorePattern()`](http://svnkit.com/kb/javadoc/org/tmatesoft/svn/core/wc/ISVNOptions.html#addIgnorePattern%28java.lang.String%29) function which should allow you to ignore file based on a given pattern.

If you want to ignore "ignore" within a specific directory, you have to set `svn:ignore` property on its parent directory, not on the file itself (as being ignored that file will never be added to repository).

```
File dir = file.getParentFile().getAbsoluteFile();
ourClientManager.getWCClient().doSetProperty(dir, SVNProperty.IGNORE,
    file.getName(), false, false, null);
```

To ignore more than one file in a directory, `svn:ignore` property value should contain a line for each ignored file, e.g:

```
a\n
b\n
*.bin
```

As soon as property is set, commit directory to make new property value be stored in repository.

Answer (score 2):

The argument list is (file, propName, propValue, force, recursive, IPropertyHandler).

So if you want to recursively apply a property, just set it 5th argument(recursive) to true.